# Redux - dependant application state

Tags: redux

I am currently trying to wrap my brain around redux and I currently have a problem understanding, how to handle dependent state in redux.

As an example think of a spreadsheet application:

In Cell A1 and A2 the user is entering values.

Cell A3 now has the following dependent state (=Sum(A1;A2))

So now, when the user enters "2" into A1 => we send an "UpdateCellAction: A1=2"
and then, he enters "4" into A2 => we send an "UpdateCellAction: A2=4"

But because of these changes, my formula in A3 has to react and also modify the state object by viewing the sum of 2 and 4, which is 6

How is something like this done in Redux?
And, what if there was another Cell B22 (whatever) which calculated another value based on A3, A2 and A1? (that state would then depend on A1, A2 and A3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common use case.  What you're looking for is the react/reselect library:

From the reselect github project page:

Selectors can compute derived data, allowing Redux to store the minimal possible state.

Selectors are efficient. A selector is not recomputed unless one of its arguments change.

Selectors are composable. They can be used as input to other selectors.

Comment: While @ghassenlouhaichi may have a point here, this actually pointed me to a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear if you consider each cell to be an individual component or not.

---

**If each cell is an individual component:**

You would use Redux to dispatch an action every time each cell is edited and keep that value under a unique key in the Redux store. You would also  use mapStateToProps to get all the values of the other components you want to calculate locally.

```
...

/**
* Redux mappings
*/
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
   cellA1: state.cells.cellA1,
   cellA2: state.cells.cellA2,
 };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
   updateCell: (newCellValue) => {
     dispatch(Actions.updateCell(newCellValue));
   },
 };
};

const ConnectedCellComponent = connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps,
)(CellComponent);
```

---

**If the spreadsheet as a whole is a component:**

You would store all the cell data in a local state object, then whenever a cell updates you would call setState() and render() would get called automatically and all the cells would recalculate appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
However, for the suggested use of "mapStateToProps", I would have to have the knowledge which cells I depend on (by parsing the formula).

Also, whenever a cell A1 changes, that another cell A3 depends on, a second action will be dispatched in order to update the value of A3.
This actually leads to two distinct sequential state changes, which is not what we need.
The change to A1 along wich updating all the dependant cells should be only one atomic operation. Otherwise undo redo would not be doable, right?